# How to check for which version of MySQL is valid my query?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to do some queries which in my local XAMPP is working fine, but, when I try on my server, the query shows empty.

I use phpinfo() to check MySQL version, on my local is 7.4 and on my server is 5.7.
The thing is my SQL query is working on server, is not showing any errors, but the response is empty, this is not happening on local.

Query:

```
SELECT
    *,
    JSON_EXTRACT(`settings`, '$.exp') AS `exp`,
    JSON_EXTRACT(`settings`, '$.status') AS `status`
FROM
    `factory_invoice`
WHERE
    `invoice` REGEXP '^[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{3}$' AND(
        JSON_CONTAINS(`settings`, '1', '$.type') OR JSON_CONTAINS(`settings`, '2', '$.type')
    ) AND(
        JSON_EXTRACT(`settings`, '$.status') = '0' OR JSON_EXTRACT(`settings`, '$.status') = '1'
    ) AND(
        JSON_EXTRACT(`settings`, '$.exp') >= '1609153609' AND JSON_EXTRACT(`settings`, '$.exp') <= '1620770400'
    )
ORDER BY
    `invoice` ASC
```

Any idea if is something from the server side? Or maybe from my SQL query?

Comment: I thing the main problem is here.........JSON_EXTRACT(`settings`, '$.exp') >= '1609153609' AND JSON_EXTRACT(`settings`, '$.exp') <= '1620770400'
    )

Comment: You want say... That sql work on xampp server... But not working your online server....

Comment: @AsifUzZaman yes, that's what I mean, is working fine on XAMPP server but not on my online server. But not exactly, because on my online server, when I try sql in phpMyAdmin, is not showing any error, just return empty.

Comment: Ok... Give me 30 mint... I waill give my server address then you can test there..

Comment: Thanks @AsifUzZaman, I already solved, I will post now solution.

Answer (score 2):

I already solved.
The problem was in JSON_EXTRACT(`settings`, '$.exp') >= '1244....
Thanks to @AsifUzZaman

I just clean a bit the code and I use BETWEEN method.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `factory_invoice`
WHERE
    `invoice` REGEXP '^[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{3}$' AND JSON_EXTRACT(`settings`, '$.type') IN(1, 2) AND JSON_EXTRACT(`settings`, '$.status') IN(0, 1) AND JSON_EXTRACT(`settings`, '$.exp') BETWEEN '1609110000' AND '1620770400'
ORDER BY
    `invoice` ASC
```

Comment: That was my first guess :-):-):-):-):-)